# Proof of the number of the leaves in a full binary tree

Tags: proof-writing, induction, trees

I need to proof by induction that at full binary tree there are $\frac{n+1}{2}$ leafs if $|V|=n$.

So, I won't write you the whole proof, just my idea, and I'd like to know if this OK...

So we assume the at full binary tree there is $\frac{n+1}{2}$ leafs for a specific  $n$.
We have to prove that the assume is correct for tree with $k=n+2$ vertices.

**How we proving it?**
We will take a tree with $n$ vertices, we know that the induction assumption is good for this tree.
Then we will take one leaf and add him 2 vertices.

So, we have a tree with $\frac{n+2-1}{2}$ leafs (because, we add 2 leafs so there is $n+2$ vertices, and we lose 1 leaf because wee add to him two children, but we get 2 leafs).

And then we get what we want to prove...

I'm right?
If not - Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Mauro, that may be true if the proof is just considering complete trees but if you are considering the broader class of trees where every node has 0 or 2 children, that argument doesn't work. I took "full binary trees" to mean this latter class, although I could be wrong.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake. If you are proving by induction on $n$, your induction hypothesis is that *all* trees of size $n$ have $\frac{n+1}{2}$ leaves and you must prove from this hypothesis that *all* trees of size $n+2$ have $\frac{(n+2)+1}{2}$ leaves. The step that you're missing is showing that all trees of size $n+2$ are extensions of trees of size $n$ - otherwise there might be some rogue tree of size $n+2$ that your argument never addressed.

If on the other hand you want to prove that if a *given* tree with $n$ vertices has $\frac{n+1}{2}$ leaves then a tree extending that tree with $n+2$ vertices has $\frac{(n+2)+1}{2}$ nodes, you are using a form of induction called *structural induction*. I am not sure whether you are allowed to use this technique.